# How to resolve Windows App Certification Kit System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: uwp, windows-store, app-certification-kit

Windows App Certification Kit was crashing when running in GUI mode.
Running it from the command line I am getting this error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
```

Description says:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program
>   Files\windowsapps\99999xxxxnk.appname_1.1.1.0_x64__bc4a78aaf2m13\AppXManifest.xml'.

This location does exist (although it is a bit hard to reach, you have to change folder ownership to see the contents), except for the four x's in my username (before ".appname"). This is from the actual error message.

Looks like something is masking the username and thus producing invalid file path (can anyone from MS help here?)

Windows App Certification Kit version is 10.0.17134.12

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of Visual Studio, it seems it helps in some cases. However, this is a [reported issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/267347/windows-app-cerfication-kit-1001713412-crashes.html) on the Visual Studio Feedback so the best approach is to vote no this issue and report you are having the problem as well so that it gets attention of the team sooner.

Comment: Thanks, did vote. No fix since June! Seems like ms is giving up on uwp...

Comment: Hopefully not, UWP is meant as the primary app development paradigm on Windows going forward. But there is a lot of issues in Visual Studio Feedback and his probably hasn't reached enough traction yet.